# change portlet title from code in Liferay without Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, yui, liferay, liferay-6

I'm having solution to change title of portlet through JQuery.

```
$('#idOfPortlet').find('.portlet-title').html('new title');
```

But we dont want to use JQuery in our project.
Is there any solution to change title of portlet using YUI or anyother thing through code?

Thanks in Advance.

Regards,
Mayur Patel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the version of Liferay you're on is using YUI 3, then this aught to do it:

```
Y.one('#idOfPortlet .portlet-title').setContent('new title');
```

I'm not sure if Liferay exposes the YUI instance as Y, or if they wrap it in AUI and make it A.

Answer (score -1):

You can do so, by using this code -

```
document.getElementsByClassName('.portlet-title')[0].content = 'something else as title'
```

Comment: This is wrong. There is no element with name "title" for portlet title, and there can be several portlets on page, so why take [0]? This is not about page title - portlet title isn't page title.

Comment: ohh.. actually this code was showing it to change title of page...
anyways you can anytime do getElementByClass and pass it whatever class is.. i modified it to reflect that way..